# Angular Aot Error - How to replace function with a reference to an exported function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I have this code

```
export function LocalStorage(key?: string) {
    return WebStorage(localStorage, key);
}

export function WebStorage(webStorage: Storage, key: string) {
        return (target: Object, propertyName: string): void => {
            key = key || propertyName;

            let storageKey = WebStorageUtility.generateStorageKey(key);
            let storedValue = WebStorageUtility.get(webStorage, key);
            ...
            Object.defineProperty(target, propertyName, {
                get: function() { ... },
                set: function(value: any) { .. },
            });
        }
    };
```

How can I get around with the following error when project is built with `--aot` flag on *angular cli*.

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function  (position 15:12 in
>   the original .ts file), resolving symbol WebStorage *in the above
>   file*.

Note: **position 15:12** is `(target: Object, propertyName: string): void => {` in the above code.

In angular components `LocalStorage` is used as property decorators e.g.

```
@LocalStorage() username: string = "";
```

Comment: How do you use the `WebStorage`, because this seems like a very normal decorator, and it should work. So I can only expect you are using it wrong somewhere, maybe you forgot the parentheses? `@WebStorage()`

Comment: Yes, this is a decorator, but wrapped by other decorators LocalStorage and SesaionStorage.

I'll post the comple code and ask. Corrently when I define inner as a separate exported function, it doesn't work because it uses a couple of variables from outer scope.

Comment: @abdul-wahab, have you solved the issue? Can use post your solution, please?

Comment: No haven't solved it yet, I am still using `--aot false` while building.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you use this *WebStorage* and it looks like a weird place to error with this but generally one would do what the error message suggest and extract the function.

So you can refactor the WebStorage function and extract the contents as a new exported method:

```
export function WebStorageInner(target: Object, propertyName: string) {
        ...
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyName, {
            get: function() { ... },
            set: function(value: any) { .. },
        });
    }
```

And the use it in the initial one:

```
export function WebStorage(webStorage: Storage, key: string) {
    ...
    return WebStorageInner(target, propertyName);
};
```

Comment: Please see how LocalStorage is used and how inner function uses key and webstorage from outer function's scope.

Comment: @abdul-wahab, This will produce `Function calls are not supported in decorators` error because of `Object.defineProperty(`.